# Determine if one range is within another

Tags: python, pandas

If there is a file with ranges sorted by the first column (no overlap of ranges):

```
1 10
12 15
18 19
```

And another, sorted by the first column (can have overlaps):

```
1 5
2 10
12 13
13 20
```

I would like to determine for each line (range)in the second file, if this line(range) intersects with any of the ranges in the first file. I did the following so far

```
df_1 = pd.read_csv('range1.txt',sep=' ')
df_2 = pd.read_csv('range2.txt',sep=' ')

for i in xrange(len(df_1)):
    start_1 = df_1.iloc[i,0]
    stop_1 = df_1.iloc[i, 1]
    for j in xrange(len(df_2)):
        start_2 = df_2.iloc[j,0]
        stop_2 = df_2.iloc[j, 1]
        if start_2 > stop_1:
            break
        elif stop_2 < start_1:
            continue
        else:
            # add ranges from second file to list
```

This I know can be terribly inefficient, so I was wondering if there is a more computationally efficient/faster way to solve this.

Comment: You will find more efficient algorithms in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree

Comment: it seems you have a typo: you should set `start_2 = df_2.iloc[j, 0]; stop_2 = df_2.iloc[j, 1]` using `j` as the index rather than `i`. Other than that I think this code is about as efficient as it can be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Olivier Pellier-Cuit has provided a [link to fast overlap test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree#Overlap_test). If you need membership check instead of overlap test, use [this algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree#Membership_queries).

So using this algorithm we can do the following:

```
df1['m'] = (df1.a + df1.b)
df1['d'] = (df1.b - df1.a)

df2['m'] = (df2.a + df2.b)
df2['d'] = (df2.b - df2.a)

df2[['m','d']].apply(lambda x: (np.abs(df1.m - x.m) < df1.d +x.d).any(), axis=1)
```

PS i've slightly simplified the calculations of `m` and `d` by getting rid of `division by 2`, because it can be done eliminating common terms.

Output:

```
In [105]: df2[['m','d']].apply(lambda x: (np.abs(df1.m - x.m) < df1.d +x.d).any(), axis=1)
Out[105]:
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
dtype: bool
```

setup:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
a b
1 10
12 15
18 19
"""), delim_whitespace=True)

df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
a b
1 5
2 10
12 13
13 20
50 60
"""), delim_whitespace=True)
```

NOTE: i've intentionally added a pair (50, 60) to the DF2, which doesn't overlap with any interval from DF1

Data frames with calculated `m` and `d` columns:

```
In [106]: df1
Out[106]:
    a   b   m  d
0   1  10  11  9
1  12  15  27  3
2  18  19  37  1

In [107]: df2
Out[107]:
    a   b    m   d
0   1   5    6   4
1   2  10   12   8
2  12  13   25   1
3  13  20   33   7
4  50  60  110  10
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know if the range of `df2` overlaps with the range of `df1`:

`if df1.ix[:,0].min() >= df2.ix[:,0].max() or df1.ix[:,0].max() <= df2.ix[:,0].min():
    print ("nope")
else:
    print ("overlap")`

Comment: I wanted to know for each line (range) in df_2, if iit intersects with any line (range) from df_1. I will update the question to include this